# Is it possible to add custom mapper for Hibernate from NUMBER database type to Java Integer?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There is a problem with mapping from Snowflake NUMBER type to Java Integer because it is not possible to set INTEGER-like database type because Snowflake converts it to NUMBER(38, 0).

You can read about it here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#int-integer-bigint-smallint-tinyint-byteint

So I would like to ask is it possible to make JPA returning `Integer` type instead of `BigInteger`?

Here is table ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    name TEXT,
    age INTEGER -- will be converted to NUMBER(38, 0) automatically
);
```

And here is JPA Repository method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT age FROM person WHERE name = :name", nativeQuery = true)
Set<Integer> findAgesByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

As a result `findAgesByName` return `Set<BigInteger>` instead of `Set<Integer>` and I receive `ClassCastException`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is correct it is converted to Numeric(38,0) to help with performance and storage.

- Documentation reference: [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#int-integer-bigint-smallint-tinyint-byteint)

Could the table methods listed here be helpful?

- JDBC API Methods:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-api.html#methods

Adding a getInt() to your query?